# Does adding "Void" solves this error?

Tags: c#, wpf

I get this error for this code here..

"Method must have a return type"

```
public ImagesGrid()
    {
      //Code
    }
```

Is it right to add "Void" in order to solve the error?

I have another identical class that does the same thing and there's no need for "void" there; that's why I'm asking..

Comment: It's probably a constructor in the other class.

Comment: The *constructor* for a class (a function of the same name as the class) does not specify a return type. Any other function *must* specify a return type.

Comment: You should definitely get a book about C# and perhaps object oriented programming in general before you start writing WPF  applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the other class is actually called `ImagesGrid()`, which makes this its constructor.

If you want an identical method in a different class and don't need a return type, then yes, you should add `void`, but what kept you from trying?

Comment: I've only changed the name from ImageGrid to C1 and that error disappeared

Comment: @user3522950 what name? Do you mean you changed `public ImagesGrid()` to `public C1()` and the error disappeared? That means your class is called `C1`. Take a look at [Constructors on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is because your other class is called ImagesGrid and thats how you make a constructor which differs from methods in every way. The constructor is being called when you instantiate a certain class.

And yes, the error that you are getting says that you must give that method a return type.

Method syntax:

```
<Access Specifier> <Return Type> <Method Name>(Parameter List) // a constructor doesnt have a return type and has the same name as its class
{                                                              
    Method Body 
}
```

So, adding void will solve the problem.